# What Is The Fastest We Have Seen Wally West Travel?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

What is the fastest that we have Wally West travel in *any* continuity?

I'm not interested in characters talking about potentially how fast they could travel. I'm only interested in them actually traveling at their top speed and the issue number that they do it in.

I'd like to know the issue number and page (image if possible) with the speed that he is travelling.

**NB:** This has been edited to be broken out into different questions per Flash.

- [Jay Garrick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217495/what-is-the-fastest-we-have-seen-jay-garrick-travel)
- [Barry Allen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217496/what-is-the-fastest-that-we-have-seen-barry-allen-travel)
- [Bart Allen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217497/what-is-the-fastest-that-we-have-seen-bart-allen-travel)

Comment: How can you think they are duplicate questions??? I'm looking for issue number of the top speed of 4 different flashes and the other question asks if the flash can travel faster than light.

Comment: I've decided to leave this open, for now, because the question which has been flagged as a duplicate is really just relative to the speed of light. It doesn't actually give us an absolute range of speed...

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: Should this perhaps be a different question for each Flash?

Comment: This question needs to be reopened, it's definitely not a duplicate

Comment: After splitting it out into separate questions the other 3 got no answers! Ergo people only care about Wally!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Wally West did it one time by running 13 trillion times the speed of light

---

In **JLA (1997): Issue # 89**, Wally West saves half a million people from an exploding nuclear warhead. Below is the image:

[image]
<sub>*JLA (1997) #89*</sub>

According to the comic, Wally carries 500,000 people 35 miles away from the blast within 0.0001 microseconds.

Although the issue doesn't specify his exact speed, it is evident that we can calculate it from the data in the image above. Also, there have been several calculations on the internet about his speed using these values; one of which is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/20512t/the_math_behind_how_the_flash_saved_a_population/).

However, almost all of them arrive to the same conclusion:

> **Wally ran about 13 trillion times the speed of light.**

<strike>And that, is the fastest one I've seen/read about in the comics.</strike>

---

**EDIT**: Another feat by Wally was when he outran teleportation in **The Flash (1987), Issue #138**

Flash [Wally] managed to go the end of the universe and back in under a plank time, which is the time it takes for light to travel a plank length which is 1.6 x 10<sup>-35</sup> m or 10<sup>-20</sup> times the size of a proton. This is the shortest distance possible, and light can do that in plank time, the smallest measurement of time that has any meaning, and is equal to 10<sup>-43</sup> seconds. This is the time it takes for teleportation, Flash beat teleportation and went past trans-time velocity, he traveled to the end of the universe and back under Plank time, i.e., he beat instantaneuos teleportation. He went at at least 23 tretacillion times the speed of light (or 23,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000). However,

> Wally gets all 5 billion people on the planet to agree to run so that he can borrow their kinetic energy and beats the space overlords in record time. Also, he is helped by a fourth-dimension alien species that are pure kinetic energy.

So, you could consider this *cheating*, from a certain point of view. Nevertheless, Wally did run faster than teleportation.

---

Couldn't find (as of now) any comic book that specifies **Jay Garrick**'s top speed. However I remember reading somwhere that his maximum speed is 99.99999% the speed of light.

---

Speaking about the Allens (**Barry** and **Bart**), once again I couldn't find any reliable source that  mentions their top speed [*like it does for Wally*].

**Sidenote**: In the Flash CW series, episode **Flashtime enter Flashtime**, we see Barry go into flash time just before a nuclear bomb is about to explode. A quick calcuation [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-fastest-speed-Barry-Allen-as-the-Flash-has-ever-achieved) says he went at 99.99999999999999982775% the speed of light.

Comment: Do you have info for the other 3 too?

Comment: @opticyclic  as I understood, your question was about the fastest among the Flashes.. if you wanted their individual top speeds, you could specify it in the question. And I will add the info accordingly

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: OK. I'm breaking it out into 4 separate questions as per the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have the comic or anything but Wally West once in a comic went faster than instant when he had to beat these alien people with a ship that could go anywhere instantly. He beats the ship which shows he’s faster than instant.

Comment: It's a pity that you can't cite a particular issue, which would answer the question more definitely. This answer is probably better framed as a comment than as an answer, unless you can pin it down.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question does specifically ask for the issue number of proposed answers.  You could make this a proper answer by looking it up and adding that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Justice League Graphic Novel Shazam went 133 trillion times the speed of light, to catch Barry Allen when he was running until his death, which means he was basically running 133 trillion times the speed of light.

Comment: Do you have the panels from the graphic novel you could [edit] in to back this up?

Comment: This question is specifically about Wally West. Can you answer on this related question about Barry Allen please https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217496/which-issue-did-barry-allen-travel-at-his-top-speed

Answer (score 0):

Technically Wally west’s speed is infinite, like all other speedsters it depends on their ability to draw energy from the speed force. Wally West has done many amazing things, on numerous occasions been seen to outrun death itself, he has run faster than the universe can expand (he basically ran into the void, before anything else could could generate), possibly the most memorable of his feats, he ran across the multiverse faster than instant teleportation. When facing off with two aliens who liked to challenge the fastest people on each planet, Wally West asked everyone on earth to run at the same time, allowing him to harness all the kinetic energy that was generated, and he ran beat them back to earth despite their abilities to teleport instantly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wants the _fastest_ time, and the specific issue (and page) that shows it.  If you think the scene with the aliens you describe is it, you need to tell us when that appeared, and how fast West moved.