# What Is The Fastest We Have Seen Jay Garrick Travel?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

What is the fastest that we have seen Jay Garrick travel in *any* continuity?

I'm interested in the issue number and page (image if possible) that he actually travels at his top speed rather than a quote saying "because of this power he can travel at this speed".

Comment: Are you looking for an actual number, or would "he can't top that speed" (with no indication of which that may be) be enough?

Comment: It has to show him traveling at a speed that you can either work out or that the panel says the speed he is traveling. So not a potential speed like you mention.