# Which Issue Did Barry Allen Travel At His Top Speed?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

I am trying to find the top speed of each Flash in *any* continuity.

What is the fastest that we have seen Barry Allen travel?

I'm interested in the issue number and page (image if possible) that he actually travels at his top speed rather than a quote saying "because of this power he can travel at this speed".

Answer (score 5):

### Superman #709 (May 2011)

[image]
Within this issue, Barry Allen both runs as well gives a “because of this power, I can…” trash talk:
[image]

> “I can think at the speed of light, I can perceive events that last for less than an Attosecond, I can run faster than time. What do I see when I run across the country, Superman? I see everything, and everyone.”

[How fast is an attosecond?](https://comicvine1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/scale_super/11128/111286280/5196271-the%20flash%20speed.jpg)
[image: “Less than a f——— attosecond”]

Comment: Having only heard about this issue before I always thought it was Wally West!

Comment: One of my favorite Flash moments was from "Flash: Rebirth" when Superman chases Barry and says something like "We've raced before, Barry. You know I can keep up with you." and then Barry says "Those were for *charity*, Clark...", then leaves Superman in his dust. Even Superman has this "whoa" expression on his face LOL