# What Is The Fastest That We Have Seen Bart Allen Travel?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash

What is the fastest that we have seen Bart Allen travel in *any* continuity?

It doesn't matter if it is when he was Impulse, Kid Flash or The Flash.

I'm interested in the issue number and page (image if possible) that he actually travels at his top speed rather than a quote saying "because of this power he can travel at this speed".